# Is a property "FullName" bad, when there are "FirstName" and "LastName"?

Tags: c#, properties

I have an `Employee` class:

```
class Employee
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Sometimes I want to get the full name and it's tedious to write `emp.FirstName + emp.LastName` again and again and again.

Is it bad practice to add a `FullName` property (because it's the same data twice or something)?

```
class Employee
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. If you use property, that is easier to call instead of concat it over and over again. What is "easy" and "clear" is always good.

Comment: What is the argument for it being a bad practice ?

Comment: You are perfectly fine to go ahead

Comment: If it simplifies your code, keep it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not the same data twice, you are actually cutting down on repeated code by adding this.

It would be bad if FullName wasn't calculated and it had to be maintained (kept in sync, set etc.) alongside FirstName/LastName.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then `FullName` property, provide `ToString()` method which can return exactly what you want to.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}
```

Take a look at MSDN documentation: [How to: Override the ToString Method (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx)

Usage:

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.FirstName = "Maciej";
emp.LastName = "Los";
Console.WriteLine("Employee: {0}", emp.ToString());
//returns: "Employee: Maciej Los"
```

Comment: I don't think overriding `ToString` is the best solution, but would prefer the `Fullname` property because of clarity. And also you could have additional properties, which may have to be considered with `ToString` but not with `Fullname`.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, this is the right way to do it. Imagine if you need to add a Title between FirstName and LastName (but only if one has been given). If you use a readonly property like your FullName everywhere you need to make just one change. If you use the two separate properties then you need to go everywhere and make the change (ifs and whatever you need to have the result properly formated)